# Allowing text areas for component attributes, rather than short inputs, within Experience Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page

In Experience Builder, we are building a custom site that makes use of many custom components that are used to handle the layout and content of the site.

One of the issues I'm struggling with is how to make the configurable component attributes for a component a bit more user-friendly when editing the site. Within our meta file for the component, I understand that the property element allows us to set the type which defines/controls this portion but I haven't seen any configuration that allows you to extend this beyond a simple input that will truncate the view of content for long sections.

An example of our current implementation:

```
<targetConfigs>
 <targetConfig target="lightningCommunity__Default">
  <property
   label="Heading"
   name="headingContent"
   type="String"
   default="Heading Placeholder"
  />
 </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Comment: This is all we get here. It is different for flow builder where you can create an LWC to handle the properties for a component... it is a real shame the different teams at Salesforce work in isolation on the various features...

Comment: That is disappointing to hear, but thank you for the response.